# How can I combine all child sprites into a single sprite?

Tags: sprite, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a scene that consists of one parent and several children, which are all Sprite2Ds, like "Body", "Clothes", "Armor", etc. I want to be able to refer to the parent as if it was a single sprite that looks like the composition of all the children sprites. So, for instance, I would like to be able to set the flip_h on the parent and have that flip all of the children. I would like to be able to refer to the texture of the parent, and have that be the image that the scene looks like, i.e., all of the sprites layered on top of each other.

I was expecting this to work just by making the parent a "Sprite2D" and adding the child sprites, but then the properties just refer to the empty texture of the parent sprite. In other posts I have seen people recommending stitching the images together in GIMP or something, but that is not going to work for me--I need control over all the behavior of all the individual layers of the overall sprite, but I want to be able to refer to the resulting sprite as if it was a single image.
I have also seen recommendations to add a camera/viewport and grab the displayed image that way, but I don't think this is a good idea in my case because I will have hundreds of these scenes and I want it to be as performant as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to try using the `SubViewport` approach. Yes, it has a performance cost, but it might not be too bad depending on your target platform and how many you use.

---

With that said, given that you want to be able to retrieve a `Texture2D`, but you do not want to use a `SubViewport`...

I'd say not use multiple `Node2D`s.

You might create an `ImageTexture`.

```
var custom_texture := ImageTexture.new()
```

And create an `Image` via code:

```
var image := Image.create(render_size.x, render_size.y, false, Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

Which you give to the `ImageTexture` using `set_image`:

```
custom_texture.set_image(image)
```

You can set your `ImageTexture` to the `texture` of the `Sprite2D`. The only `Sprite2D`:

```
%sprite.texture = custom_texture
```

You can create a new `image` and set it with `set_image` replacing the old one.

*In fact, (not necessary, but the usability might be worth it) you can create a class that `extends ImageTexture` and has all the drawing code internally, and calls `set_image` on itself.*

To draw on the `image` you can, for example use `blit_rect`. This is an example that draws `icon.png`:

```
var source := preload("res://icon.png").get_data()
image.blit_rect(source, Rect2(Vector2.ZERO, source.get_size()), Vector2.ZERO)
```

There the `Rect2` is the source area (the area of the image we are drawing that we want to draw) which goes from Vector2.ZERO to the size of the image. The other Vector2.ZERO is the position where we want to draw it.

*I'm adapting the above code from a prior answer: [How can I bake 2D sprites in Godot at runtime?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/197056/10408).*

The trouble with this approach is that the API does not support drawing a rotated image. Thus if you need that, you would have to set the pixels one by one... Even if the API supported drawing a rotated image, it would be doing it CPU anyway. Thus, this approach won't be as performant as letting the GPU handle it.

The situation in which using `ImageTexture` would have the most performance edge in its favor is when the `image` is not updated often.

---

There are other ways to get what you want drawn on the screen which are more performant, including using `_draw` (see [Custom drawing in 2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/custom_drawing_in_2d.html)), and using the `RenderingServer` (see [Optimization using Servers](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/performance/using_servers.html)), but you would still have the problem of getting a `Texture2D` out of it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I tried implementing the viewport approach, but I can't get it to work. I have the root node of the scene as a Sprite2D, with a child SubViewportContainer, with a child SubViewport, and the child of that is all of the individual component sprites. Then, I set the texture of the parent sprite to a new viewport texture, pointing to the sub viewport. But when I try to grab the texture of the main node, it is blank. I also tried leaving the root node as a blank Node2D, and manually capturing from the viewport, but that was also blank.

Comment: @DawsonEliasen Three things: 1. Don't use a SubViewportContainer, have the `SubViewport` (it won't show). 2. Set a `Sprite2D` where you use a `ViewportTexture` linking the `SubViewport` (this is how it shows), I recommend setting the `Sprite2D` *after* the the `SubViewport` in the scene tree (not as parent, not as child - when the `Sprite2D` loads the `SubViewport` must exist already). 3. You might get a couple frame blank if you try to read the texture from code, you need to `await RenderingServer.frame_post_draw` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't know the Sprite2D needed the Subviewport to exist already, I kept trying to put the Sprite2D higher in the scene tree. It's basically doing what I want now.